# How to format date while displaying in the view file in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting date from my database in the form `2016-06-01` but am interested in displaying it like `May 31st, 2013` in the view file.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php date function, and refer to the [date php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.date.php)

Comment: date('F jS, Y', strtotime($date))

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to get it done.

```
date('F jS, Y', strtotime($date))
```

Comment: `@L. feir` gave an answer with this `date()` function over a week ago, why didn't you accept his?

Comment: @reformed: I have no objection but won't you think that answer should be more detailed

Comment: The only difference in detail with your answer are parameters for the `date()` function referenced in the other answer. Because of this, it would have been better to simply add such as a comment to his answer.